# Custom zoom to Google line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I've being using the `dragToZoom` explorer function to add zoom functionality to my line charts.

```
explorer: { 
    actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
    axis: 'horizontal',
    keepInBounds: true,
    maxZoomIn: 4.0
}
```

Fiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4w626v2s/2/).

I also wanted to add a custom zoom where the user would choose a start date and the chart would be zoomed into the period [start date; current date].

I saw that the [Annotation Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart) offer a method called `setVisibleChartRange(start, end)` that could do it. However, I tried them on my application and they are not as view pleasing and customizable as [Line Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) are (legends, borders, etc).

Is there any way of changing the visible range on line charts?

Comment: [there are controls](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#controls-gallery) you can use to filter any chart -- the `ChartRangeFilter` is similar to the control at the bottom of an `AnnotationChart` -- `DateRangeFilter` is also available...

Comment: @WhiteHat I had seen these controls. The `ChartRangeFilter` is the one which is the closest to what the application needs.  Do you think I can programmatically change `range.start` and `range.end` in its state properties?

Comment: sure, use the `setState` method --> `filter.setState({range: {start: a, end: b}})`

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do it without using Annotation Charts was following WhiteHat's tip on the comment, adding a [CharRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) and changing its state.

As mentioned in Google Developers [page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#8-programmatic-changes-after-draw), the `draw()` method needs to be called after changing the state:

> The rule of thumb is to perform any change you need directly on the specific `ControlWrapper` (or `ChartWrapper`) instance: for example, change a control option or state via `setOption()` and `setState()` respectively, and call its `draw()` method afterward.

```
var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ComboChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
        legend: { 
          position: 'bottom', 
          alignment: 'center', 
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 12
          }
      },
      explorer: {
          actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
          axis: 'horizontal',
          keepInBounds: true
      },
      hAxis: {
          title: 'X'
      },
      pointSize: 3,
      vAxis: {
          title: 'Y'
      }
  }
});

var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control_div',
    options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0,
        ui: {
            chartOptions: {
                height: 50,
                chartArea: {
                    width: '75%'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

dash.bind([control], [chart]);

dash.draw(data);

// example of a new date set up
setTimeout(function () {        
    control.setState({range: {
        start: new Date(2016, 6,1),
      end: new Date()
  }});
  control.draw();
}, 3000);
```

I created a working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hicaro/vk8oaryy/8/).